# EF Reverse Engineer Code First does not populate one-to-many & many-to-many properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm not sure if I'm doing things wrong or EF has a bug. I followed this StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228600/ef-code-first-many-to-many-and-one-to-many) but to my avail, it still failed to populate. The structure is basically the same.

I'm absolutely sure on the data since the keys match up to the data. Eventually, I ended up just manipulating the models in my Service layer just to populate the properties.

```
        public TeamsService(IRepositoryAsync<Team> repo, IRepositoryAsync<AspNetUser> userRepo)
            : base(repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
            _userRepo = userRepo;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Team>> GetAllTeams()
        {
            var teams = await _repo.Queryable().ToListAsync();
            teams.ForEach(t => t.Creator = _userRepo.Find(t.CreatorId));
            return teams;
        }
```

This work around does the job just fine. The foreign key Id's are all integers, so I doubt it was having a mismatch.

Comment: Did you use the latest EF Tools? Version 6,1,3 contains improvements to sql server schema discovery

Comment: Hi Erik, afaik I've the latest EF tools. Any other leads?

Comment: Are you sure? It is a separate download post vs 2013 update 4

Comment: Can you post a link to the vsix? Thanks

Comment: It is a msi, but sure: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2015/03/10/ef6-1-3-rtm-available.aspx

Comment: Cheers, I've got the latest 6.1.3 Entity Framework version from NuGet and I'm using the EF Power tools VS plug-in (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d/). I'll try this one out.

Comment: So I've installed the tools and attempted to re-generate the models & data context. I've compared the models, data context, and mapping data with the one I originally generated. They do not have any difference. It still does not populate the properties. How exactly does this help me? Thanks.

Comment: It is solved. Here's my answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542993/generic-unit-of-work-and-repository-pattern-does-not-load-related-entities/29543154#29543154