# Generic Unit of Work and Repository pattern does not load related entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I actually had a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29540395/ef-reverse-engineer-code-first-does-not-populate-one-to-many-many-to-many-prop?noredirect=1#comment47235227_29540395) regarding the topic that I first thought was an EF issue. I then realized that EF has a lazy loading configuration built in and it appears that the [Generic Unit of Work and Repository Pattern framework](https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/) is not loading related entities automatically.

When I use the .Include() extension in the DBSet<> property, the relationships begin populating without issue.

This works:

```
var list = (new DBContext()).Teams.Include(a => a.Creator).AsQueryable().ToList();
```

Using the repository does not work:

```
var list = _repo.Queryable().ToListAsync();
```

Any help, please?

**UPDATE FIX:**

Thanks to DLeh for the idea!
Here's my fix:

```
var list = _repo.Queryable().Include(a => a.Creator).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: can you show us the code for the `_repo.Queryable()` method?

Comment: Ah! Brilliant! Thanks for the idea. The Queryable() is actually the DBSet object! Thanks, this fixed it

Answer (score 0):

It's solved. Thanks to DLeh for the idea.

```
var list = _repo.Queryable().Include(a => a.Creator).ToListAsync();
```